# Change the url on click of tabs in ngx boostrap tabs in angular

Tags: angular

I have a component with four tabs (using ngx-bootstrap tabs) myprod,mysettings,etc. and I created four different routing for each tab(pointed to same component). and I used the below code for show the right tab on page load.

```
[routerLink]="['/user/my-account']" [routerLinkActive]="'active is-active'"
```

but it's not working for ngx boostrap tabs

Comment: try using `[class.active]="selectedUrl=='/user/my-account'"`

Comment: can you please explain what is selectedUrl here

Comment: selectedUrl is a variable so create a variable like selectedUrl to store the current active url value on the variable

Comment: can you please exlpain in an example